# Align glyphicon beside header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align a glyphicon beside my header.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, knowing which version of bootstrap you are working with would help as would seeing enough of the code to determine what you've set up already.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a `<span>` directly before the header text:

```
<div class="h2">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
  Blacklisting
</div>
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/xMbQvvIr4l

This assumes you're on Bootstrap 3.0.+

Answer (score 0):

Use float

CSS

```
.glypic{

  float:left;
  postion:relative;
         }
  .myheader{
   float:left;
   postion:relative;
   margin-left:5px;
    }
```

Html

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="glypic">
    <img src="img/glypic.png">
  </div>
  <div class="myheader">
       <h2>Blacklisting</h2>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you out:

```
.header div{float:left;margin-right:5px;}
```